# nginx - debug_connection http upstream connect: -2

Tags: nginx

What does `http upstream connect: -2` mean  in error.log ?

I have enabled connection debugging (hoping to pool connection for upstream using domain name)

```
events {
   debug_connection wzample.com;
}
```